# Getting operator errors in Java while using vector

Tags: java

I am using vector as a parameter in function...
I dont know how to resolve these operator errors.

```
stt.java:8: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
                                product=ar.get(i)*ar.get(j);
                                                 ^
  first type:  Object
  second type: Object
stt.java:16: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
                if(ar.get(i)>ar.get(ind1))
                            ^
  first type:  Object
  second type: Object
stt.java:20: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
                if((ar.get(i)!=ar.get(ind1)) && (ar.get(i)>ar.get(ind2)))
                                                          ^
  first type:  Object
  second type: Object
stt.java:23: error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
        return ar.get(ind1)*ar.get(ind2);
                           ^
  first type:  Object
  second type: Object
5 errors
```

The code is:

```
import java.util.*;
class stt{
static long maxPairwiseProduct(Vector ar, int n){
    long product=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=n-1;j++){
            if(product <((ar.get(i))*(ar.get(j))) )
                product=ar.get(i)*ar.get(j);
        }
    }
    return product;
}
static long maxPairwiseProductFast(Vector ar, int n){
    int ind1=0,ind2=0;
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        if(ar.get(i)>ar.get(ind1))
            ind1=i;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
        if((ar.get(i)!=ar.get(ind1)) && (ar.get(i) > ar.get(ind2)))
            ind2=i;
    }
    return ar.get(ind1)*ar.get(ind2);
}
static void stressTest(int N,int M){
    Random ran= new Random();
    Vector<Integer> vec= new Vector<Integer>(N);
    //int[] arr= new int[N];
    while(true){
        int n=ran.nextInt(N)+2;
            for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++){
                vec.add(ran.nextInt(M));
            }
            long r1= maxPairwiseProduct(vec,n);
            long r2= maxPairwiseProductFast(vec,n);
            if(r1==r2){
                System.out.println("OK");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Wrong Answer: "+r1+" "+r2);

            }
    }

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    int N=1000000;
    int M=1000000;
    stressTest(N,M);
}
}
```

How to solve the error??
Problem coming at the part:

```
if(product <((ar.get(i))*(ar.get(j))) )
                    product=ar.get(i)*ar.get(j);
```

and

```
if((ar.get(i)!=ar.get(ind1)) && (ar.get(i) > ar.get(ind2)))
                ind2=i;
```

Comment: You're trying to multiply objects. First, use `List` (not `Vector`). Secondly, you shouldn't use rawtypes, so `List<Long>` instead of `List`

Comment: Btw, if you need `long` precision in the result, you should use `long` (or `Long`) operands in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not know about the content type of the vector. In your method the parameter type is just `Vector`, this is called a 'raw' type in Java, in contrast to the parameterized type `Vector<Integer>`. This leaves the compiler to assume the contents as type `Object`, as displayed in the error output. Using the parameterized type instead, the content type is `Integer`, on which multiplication and comparison work because of the underlying 'auto-unboxing' feature in Java.